# What does "+N levels damage in combat" mean in Geneforge 2?

Tags: geneforge-2

GF2 has some equipment kicking around with this modifier on it, such as the Student's Belt (+1 levels damage in combat) and the Thrusting Gauntlets (+2 levels damage in combat). But what does it actually do? The obvious interpretation is that it makes you hit as though you were N levels higher, but attack damage doesn't (at least according to the manual) actually scale with character level -- only with one of your stats (str or dex, depending on the weapon) + your melee or ranged skill.

Does it act as though you have +N to the relevant skill when attacking? Does it give +N to all damage dice in the attack, or +N dice? Whatever it does, does it affect spells too, or only melee and ranged physical attacks?

Comment: Prettu sure it's +n skill levels, but waiting to make that an answer until I can look a few things up.

Comment: @Sterno Any word on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most spiderweb software games, Geneforge 2 uses dice to calculate attack damage. You can find out what kind of dice a weapon or spell uses by dividing its maximum damage with its minimum damage.

For example, a dagger deals 2-14 damage so 14/2=7 means the dagger uses d7 to calculate damage. I've found that all weapons in Geneforge 2 use the same die, but that may not be the case of spells.

The amount of dice is the base amount for the weapon or spell plus strength, melee, bows, spellcraft, etc. Of course a melee attack isn't improved by spellcraft while a spell isn't improved by strength.

+N levels damage in combat adds N dice to every damage roll your character does. This modifier is particularly useful for characters that use both normal attacks and spells regularly like the agent.

Source: http://spiderwebforums.ipbhost.com/index.php?/topic/12456-levels-damage/